# работа с фреймворком в разных приложениях c помощью Git

Tags: php, git, framework, git-submodule

К примеру: у меня есть фреймворк. Я его постепенно разрабатываю. 
В какой то момент я хочу использовать фреймворк в другом проекте. 
Как организовать работу с GIT так, чтобы я отдельно мог обновлять фреймворк, дописывая сверху функциональность?
Вариант "клонировать фреймворк, удаить папку .git и клонировать новый фреймворк под проект" кажется не верным.

Comment: Кстати, если какой-то из ответов вас удовлетворяет и решает вашу задачу, вы можете принять его (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одним из вариантов является подключение фреймворка как **подмодуля** git.
У нас фреймворк лежит в git отдельным репозиторием. В каждом проекте в корне мы подключаем фреймворк как `git submodule`. Например, вот так:

```
git submodule add git@github.com:_OWNER_/framework.git framework
```

Это позволяет отдельно развивать фреймворк и проекты, т.е. коммиты в родительский репозиторий не будут автоматически коммитить измения в подумодулях, и наоборот - изменения в подмодулях не влекут за собой изменение родительского репозитория. Если во фреймворке появляются новые коммиты, и вы хотите апнуть фреймворк в проектах, то в проектах нужно будет сделать:

```
cd framework
git fetch
git checkout origin/master   #переключаем фреймворк на последнюю версию мастера
cd ..
git add framework
git commit -m 'up framework'
```

Фреймворк можно обновить еще и так (вместо строк 2 и 3)

```
git pull
```

или

```
git checkout master
git merge origin/master
```

Но, если вы вдруг вносили *временные* правки внутри подмодуля, то могут возникнуть конфликты при `merge`. Придётся тратить время на их исправление. А `git checkout origin/master` просто переключит ревизию на последнюю. А в случае "конфликтных" изменений в файлах - выдаст предупреждение.

Развёртывание проекта с подмодулем фреймворка будет таким:

```
git clone YOUR-PROJECT project
cd project
git submodule update --init  #фреймворк подтянется к проекту
```

При этом при загрузке (пуше) на сервер (Github, Bitbucket и т.п.), код проекта не будет содержать код фреймворка (подмодуля) в чистом виде, папки подмодулей будут отображаться в виде ссылок на соответствующие им репозитории.

Здесь можно почитать более подробно:

- [Инструменты Git - Подмодули](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8)
- [Подмодули](http://uleming.github.io/gitbook/5_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8.html)

Comment: @NickVolynkin да, спс, можно и `git pull`. Просто как то `git pull` не использую в последнее время. `git fetch` + `git merge` - точно знаем что и куда вливаем :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin точно. `checkout` тоже можно, даже еще лучше чем `merge` на мой взгляд. Т.к. если вдруг есть какие то изменённые файлы, после merge придётся исправлять конфликты. А при checkout git нам сообщит об этом.

Comment: кстати, у нас тут есть чат про гит, заходите: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26116/git--ru-so

Comment: Во, теперь совсем хорошо  )

Comment: @NickVolynkin спасибо за наводки и дополнения )

Answer (score 1):

возможно вам стоит взглянуть на средство для подобных целей.

**Composer**  — это относительно новый и уже достаточно популярный менеджер зависимостей для PHP. Вы можете описать от каких библиотек зависит ваш проект и Composer установит нужные библиотеки за вас! Причём Composer — это не менеджер пакетов в классическом понимании. Да, он оперирует с сущностями, которые мы будем называть «пакетами» или библиотеками, но устанавливаются они внутрь каждого проекта отдельно, а не глобально (это одно из основных отличий от старого-доброго `PEAR`).

Кратко, как это работает:
У вас есть проект, который зависит от нескольких библиотек.
Некоторые из этих библиотек зависят от других библиотек.
Вы описываете в своём проекте те библиотеки, от которых непосредственно зависит ваш код.
Composer находит нужные версии требуемых библиотек для всего проекта, скачивает их и устанавливает в папку вашего проекта.

> https://getcomposer.org/

где Ваш фреймворк будет находится в отдельном **git** репазитарии. И с помощью **Composer** потягивается к проектам которые будут использовать Ваш фреймворк